# How to input a double number in an Edittext Dialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, double

For the last days I have been trying to implement a Edittext Dialog which the user introduces a double number (e.g.: 1.15) and then the application will transform this double number into decimal and hexadecimal value but I don't know hot to implement this case.

Here is the code I have implemented to show the Edittext Dialog:

```
else if (uuid.equals(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.AdvInterval)){
                final EditText passtext = new EditText(v.getContext());
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                .setTitle("AdvInterval Modification")
                .setMessage("Please, introduce the new Advertising Time Interval (max 2 decimals):")
                .setView(passtext)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // Code to obtain the the bit array/int from the edittext box
                    }

                })
                .show();
            }
```

Comment: Which is the problem? You can insert everything you want inside your EditText obtaining a String that you can parse to get the decimal number you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert a `String` to a `Double` use:

```
Double mydouble = Double.parseDouble(passText.getText());
```

To make sure the `Double` only has 2 decimal places use:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
myDouble = Double.parseDouble(df.format(myDouble));
```